# Write a shell script that find-greps files and outputs only those filenames

Tags: bash, shell, grep, find

I want to search files in particular folder and content, then I want to print only the name of the files found.
I have a command:

```
for file in $(find from | xargs grep 'move')
do 
   echo $file
done
```

It prints eg:

```
from/1.txt:move
from/2.txt:some text
move
from/3.txt:move text
```

But I want:

```
from/1.txt
from/2.txt
from/3.txt
```

I tried to cut that unnecessary part by using:

```
${file%:*}
```

this gives result:

```
from/1.txt
from/2.txt
move
from/3.txt
```

That 'move' is left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep has a recursive as well as a 'just list filename' option, so this should work:

```
grep -r -l "move" from
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the option `-l` to `grep`, i.e.

```
for file in $(find from | xargs grep -l 'move')
do 
   echo $file
done
```

Or even better:

```
for file in $(find from -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 grep -l 'move')
do 
   echo $file
done
```